# Zener voltage regulator circuit question

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

I'm repairing a power supply, which has the following circuit:
[image: zenerregulator]

It looks like a Zener regulator but have this strange 1K resistor in red. Does anyone knows what is the purpose of this?

I'm also trying to figure out the zener value, it measured inconsistently values, i guess it has failed.

Vout must be 15v.

Comment: It may act to drain off the zener voltage to a certain extent if the output is short circuited. While it's far from being proper short circuit protection, maybe in context (input V, transistor ratings, etc) it allows some accidents to be survivable?

Comment: @BrianDrummond, agreed, and it also has a side effect of applying the voltage gradually, because the capacitor is initially a "short" to ground... perhaps intentionally?